# Progressbar not displaying when TextView has content

Tags: java, android-linearlayout

I'm working with a class that extends `Dialog`. It should display a `progressbar` element.  Sometimes there will be a message, sometimes there isn't.

The `progressbar` shows when there is no message but does not show when there is a message and I do not understand why.

Here is the layout code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_message"
    style="@style/arial"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Here is the java:

```
public void progressDialog () {    
    if(this.message.getText().length() > 0){
        message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    leftButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    rightButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

When `message` is set `GONE` the progressbar shows, when `message` is set `VISIBLE` the progressbar does not show.  I assume it is getting hidden by the message somehow.

I've tried moving it around in the layout as this question might suggest was needed [ProgressBar not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149428/progressbar-not-displaying), but to no avail.

How do I get the progressbar to always show when calling `progressDialog()`?

Edit*****  Added full layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
    style="@style/arialBold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="@string/waiting"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="21sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_message"
    style="@style/arial"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:text=" "
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_button_one"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/purple"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_button_one_text"
            style="@style/arialBold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/alert_dialog_button_margin_left_right"

android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/alert_dialog_button_margin_left_right"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"

            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_button_two"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:background="@color/purple"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_button_two_text"
            style="@style/arialBold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/alert_dialog_button_margin_left_right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/alert_dialog_button_margin_left_right"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I was just investigating constraint Layout @Zeeshan.  I suspect to fix this I will need to rework the entire layout based on a constraint model, which there isn't time for now - this not being a priority.  If someone (@Arsalan Khan, @Zeeshan) can explain **Why** these alternate layout modes are necessary then happy to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using linear layout. So use Relative Layout instead of linear layout.

Comment: that messes the whole display up?  I want these to display linearly vertically, so linear layout should be fine.  In the IDE they position themselves fine when adding the components with all elements visible?

Comment: does you set fixed height of your dialog layout?

Comment: Layout height is set to wrap_content, but when he progress spinner does not display the dialog has space for it. i.e. it doesn't shrink the window. (I'll add full layout xml to question)

Answer (score 0):

Add a parent constraint layout to your linear layout and move progress bar out of linear layout.

```
<constraint>
   <linear/>
   <progress/>
</constraint>
```

Some thing like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
    >


    <!-- Your complete layout -->

</LinearLayout>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Just wrapping & moving progress out didn't work.  See comment I have added to original question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like you use some wrong property for what you want, look:

**android:layout_gravity="center"** will put your **TextView** in center of the layout, but you also set it in your **ProgressBar** this mean that only one of then will be shown, it is only useful when you want to show one view at time, if you want to show both, try to remove one of this property.

Another thing, you set **android:layout_margin="30dp"** on TextView, so your progressBar will be far removed from TextView, which may also cause the invisibility of the ProgressBar, try **16dp**.

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/dialog_message"
style="@style/arial"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center" // remove here or in ProgressBar
android:layout_margin="16dp" // I just replace 30dp to 16dp
android:text=" "
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textSize="20sp" />
```

**EDIT - Another Answer**

I edit your full XML code, replacing some margin with padding, and show the progressBar always. You can now hide/show the textView or progressbar, it should work.

I also replace some property, since I have not it here, make sure to add again. Hope it help you.

I recommend to use RelativeLayout to improve your UI. Below I show the current XML behavior.

[image: When ProgressBar is hided]

When ProgressBar is showed

[image]

The full source code on link below, I am unable to paste the code here.

https://gist.github.com/pedromassango/a6dc213823b297931f1ef2e6b6954466

Comment: These sounded promising, but unfortunately didn't work.  I tried removing gravity on each element in turn, still no spinner showing

Comment: Thank you for your persistence, but this is still not working in my code, there must be something else going on and I will have to investigate further

Comment: To always show your progressbar, just never call progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);